# Converting year of birth variable into age variable in R

Tags: r

I'm working on a dataset from 2009. I have a variable with the birth years of the respondents, which I would like to recode into an age variable. I guess the easiest way to do so is to subtract from 2009 the dates of birth of all observations of the column of the dataframe, but I don't know how, because I am still new to R (I have been working with Stata so far). What is the easiest way to do the recoding?

Here is the head of my data frame. The column with the year of birth is e2:

```
                d6c            d7a         d7b       d7c            d7d e1   e2           e3 e3a
1           neither      no answer Q not asked no answer      no answer  1 1961 in [country]  -1
2             agree          agree Q not asked     agree strongly agree  1 1945 in [country]  -1
3             agree          agree Q not asked   neither          agree  1 1945 in [country]  -1
4 strongly disagree strongly agree Q not asked  disagree       disagree  0 1961 in [country]  -1
                          e4 e4a e4b e6a         e6b                                           e7 e7a e8
1         large town or city  -1  48  -1 Q not asked                   other, not in labour force  -1 -1
2 small or middle-sized town  -1  63  -1 Q not asked employed full-time [32 hrs or more per week]  -1 -1
3      rural area of village  -1  64  -1 Q not asked                                      retired  -1 -1
4      rural area of village  -1  48  -1 Q not asked               employed part-time [15-32 hrs]  -1 -1
                        e9                               e10                          e11        e12a
1                    never                              None married or living as married Q not asked
2                    never                              None married or living as married Q not asked
3     2 or 3 times a month Protestant, no denomination given married or living as married Q not asked
4 a number of times a year                    Roman Catholic married or living as married Q not asked
         e12b        e12c e13 e14 e15a e15b
1 Q not asked Q not asked  -1  -1   -1   -1
2 Q not asked Q not asked  -1  -1   -1   -1
3 Q not asked Q not asked  -1  -1   -1   -1
4 Q not asked Q not asked  -1  -1   -1   -1
```

Comment: If `e2` is of class integer/numeric you can do `2009 - df$e2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  e2 = c(1967, 1977, 1988, 1955, 2000, 1969)
)
```

To get age, simply subtract `df$e2` from 2009:

```
df$age <- 2009 - df$e2
df
    e2 age
1 1967  42
2 1977  32
3 1988  21
4 1955  54
5 2000   9
6 1969  40
```

If `e2` is of type character, convert to type numeric:

```
df$age <- 2009 - as.numeric(df$e2)
```